# Changing the sound setting from the command line

Tags: sound, settings

I frequently switch between two sound settings: One directly connecting an analog headphone to the computer, and another is I connect an audio device to the HDMI audio output on the monitor. I want to switch between them quickly by writing a short script to switch between the two settings. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

I think you should be looking at something like this:

`alsactl save CARD #` to save the configuration
`alsactl restore CARD #` to restore the configuration